# Animate image scale change while preserving its width and height

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, caanimation

I want to animate zooming-in and out from image in Swift using `CAAnimation` while preserving the original width and height of the image (i.e. show smaller area in the image enlarged).

I tried to use the following animation and it did animate the change in scale properly, but also changed the width and height of my image accordingly:

```swift
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
animation.fromValue = 1.4
animation.toValue = 1.0
animation.duration = 2

self.imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "scaleAnimation")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to put the image view in a container view with the container view's `clipToBounds` set to `true`. This way as the image view is scaled larger, it will be clipped by its container view and appear to remain the same size. Make sure the container view's frame matches the unzoomed size of the image view.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to allow one subview of this container view to be out of the container view's frame? I have one subview that should be out of it, and now it is not visible at all.

Comment: Create another container view that contains the image view container and this other view that you need.